# row_number() function over aggregate values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Implementing `row_number()` function over aggregate values in `MySQL` as following:

```
select 
section,
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 
        FROM rpt_top_uv_hosts_d
        WHERE rpt_date>='2017-06-07' and rpt_date<='2017-06-08' and section is not null and section = a.section
        AND sum(uv) > a.uv
        group by section,room_id,domain,name ) as 'Rank',
sum(uv) as 'uv',
room_id,
domain,
name
from rpt_top_uv_hosts_d a
where rpt_date>='2017-06-07' and rpt_date<='2017-06-08' and section is not null
group by section,room_id,domain,name
order by section,Rank asc;
```

The main purpose is to rank `room_id` by its corresponding `uv` during selected days. However, `MySQL` returns only one sentence: '`Invalid use of group function`'.

What is the reason of this issue? `group by` is not allowed in a sub-query? And how to address this issue? By the way, SQL variable is not allowed in this BI system.

Thanks for your help in advance..

---

I solve this question by multi sub-query, but the SQL looks bad.. Hope this can be optimized.

```
select 
    section,
    (select count(*)+1 from (select section,sum(uv) as uv_aggre,room_id,domain,name
    from rpt_top_uv_hosts_d
    WHERE rpt_date>='2017-06-07' and rpt_date<='2017-06-08' and section is not null
    group by section,room_id,domain,name) a 
    where a.section = demo.section AND a.uv_aggre > demo.uv_aggre) as rank,
    uv_aggre,
    name,
    room_id,
    domain
from
(select section,sum(uv) as uv_aggre,room_id,domain,name
from rpt_top_uv_hosts_d
WHERE rpt_date>='2017-06-07' and rpt_date<='2017-06-08' and section is not null
group by section,room_id,domain,name) as demo
order by section,rank;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some mysql version, the group by has to have all the field you have in the select statement. So you have to group by rank as well in the way the query is done.
Could you try to rerun with rank in the last group by and see what happens? Sorry I can't just comment your post as I am too new.
[#sqlmode_only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

also, rewrite this using HAVING, I didn't see that you where using an aggregate function in the where, let me know :)

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)+1 
    FROM rpt_top_uv_hosts_d
    WHERE rpt_date>='2017-06-07' and rpt_date<='2017-06-08' and section is 
    not null and section = a.section

    group by section,room_id,domain,name 
    HAVING  sum(uv) > a.uv
```

Comment: Try also:  group by section,room_id,domain,name 
    HAVING  sum(uv) > a.uv as it is a aggregate function and should be having not in where. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation~ I didn't think of HAVING